# submit on any update to text field- python

Tags: jquery, python, html, jinja2

Im new to python and web programming. I have some working html and python code in app engine, using jinja2 and webapp2 libraries, that returns query results based on what the user inputs into a text box and then hits submit. I would like to change my code so my POST code runs whenever the text box is updated and no submit button is needed. Any code samples or guidance on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

My html body

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <div><input type="text" name="content" class="input-block-level" rows="1" value="{{ textInput }}"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" value="Submit"></div>
    <div><label>Query Time(ms): </label><label>{{ queryTime }}</label></label></div>

  </form>
  {% for product in products %}
  <div class="row">
  <blockquote>{{ product }}</blockquote>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

My Python main page with get and post

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
    textInput = ""
    products = ""
    queryTime = 0
    template_values = {
        'products': products,
        'textInput': textInput,
        'queryTime': queryTime,
    }

    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

def post(self):
    textInput = self.request.get('content').lower()
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')

    t1= time.time()
    product_query = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Product where name >= :1 LIMIT 5",textInput)
    results = product_query.fetch(5)
    t2= time.time()

    products = []

    for counter, names in enumerate(results):
        if counter == 0:
            if not names.name.lower().startswith(textInput.lower()):
                products.append("No Matches")
        if names.name.startswith(textInput.lower()):
            products.append(names.name) 


    queryTime = (t2 - t1) * 1000

    template_values = {
        'products': products,
        'textInput': textInput,
        'queryTime': queryTime,
    }

    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use: **onkeyup event** for input, which **make ajax call** to your **ajax webapp2 handler**.